# I have been trying to convert "Mon Jan 21 2019 20:06:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)" into (01/21/2019 20:06:48 ) this format In java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

OR

```
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

I have the format of time in data bases tables and I have to convert them into `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or `MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss`

Input : `Mon Jan 21 2019 20:06:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

Expected output : `01/21/2019 20:06:48`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You'll need two `DateTimeFormatter` objects (or equivalent) - one to parse your `String`, and another to format the result.

Comment: If your date and time are stored as `datetime` or `timestamp` in your database, don’t get then as a string. A modern JDBC driver or JPA implementation will be happy to get them as an appropriate type from java.time for you (for example `OffsetDateTime`).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. If you do need parsing and also for formatting use  `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

21 January, 2019 is a Monday not a Thursay, Java'll throws an error when parsing

---

You need an formatter to parse your string, and a formatter to print the date like you want

- if your system use by default `Locale.ENGLISH` you can remove it) :

```
String input = "Mon Jan 21 2019 20:06:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)";

DateTimeFormatter inFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (z)");
DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");

OffsetDateTime od = OffsetDateTime.parse(input, inFormatter);

System.out.println(od);                         // 2019-01-21T20:06:48-04:00
System.out.println(od.format(outFormatter));    // 01/21/19 20:06:48
```

Comment: Close, but that is not the input string (ignoring the day-of-week issue), you're missing the `(EDT)` at the end of the input.

Comment: @Andreas done ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use pattern `"EE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (z)"`?

Comment: I agree with @Andreas here. You are parsing `GMT` into a time zone that is not the time zone of the time, which `OffsetDateTime` then fortunately ignores. Requiring `'GMT'` littterally would seem to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Andreas sure, my bad